# net/http request just coming back with 200's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, net-http

I am using net/http in rails to get back the response codes from URL's with the following code;

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"


class Status
def initialize(url)
    @url = url
end

def get_status 
    begin 
        response.code
    rescue Exception => e
        Rails.logger.info("Error #{e}")
    end
end

def active?
    ["200","203","302","301"].include?(get_status) ? true : false
end

private

def lookup
    URI.parse(@url)
end
def http
    Net::HTTP.new(lookup.host, lookup.port)
end
def request
    Net::HTTP::Get.new(lookup.request_uri)
end
def response
    http.request(request)
end
end
```

Although it correctly marks failures it displays the code for all whether pass or failure as status code: 200, how can I get the correct status code?

**Controller:**

```
class EnvironmentsController < ApplicationController
  def status
    app = App.find(params[:app_id])
    environment = app.environments.find{|env| env.id.to_s == params[:id]}
    render json: {up:environment.up?}
  end
end
```

**View:**

```
<%- App.all.each do |app| %>
  <h3><%= app.name %></h3>

  <ul class="app" data-app-id="<%= app.id %>">
    <%- app.environments.each do |environment| %>
      <li class="env" data-env-id="<%= environment.id %>">
      <strong><%= environment.name %></strong>
      <%= environment.url %><span class="status"> Loading. . . </span>
      <!-- <i> Status Code: <% puts response.code %></i> </li> -->
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

Comment: `Status.new("http://example.com/unknown").get_status` returns `404`

Comment: Have you got any other tool that shows a different response code from same URL?

Comment: So I am getting the URL's from a database and going through them one by one, how would I implement the Status.new solution to the code above?

Comment: @Phillip-Marsden please post that code, i.e. the part that's not working / always returning 200.

Comment: That is the complete code above

Comment: The terminal provides the 200's after each url parsed, I am wanting to use <%= response.code %> after each URL in the view but it comes back with 200's everytime in both the terminal and view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using your `Status` class. In your view `response` refers to the current response.

So instead of:

```
Status Code: <% puts response.code %>
```

Try:

```
Status Code: <%= Status.new(environment.url).get_status %>
```